# Can home solar power installations be deducted as a business expense?

Tags: united-states, taxes, tax-deduction, limited-liability-company, california

I run computer servers at home 24/7, and my home is in California. To power them, I would like to install solar panels and home battery backup system. Can I deduct this as a business expense for my California LLC?

The concern I have here is that I need to separate energy for home use vs. energy for business use.

Comment: I've added the `capital-expenditure` tag, since that's what the question is about.

Comment: Business capital expenditures are typically depreciated over a number of years.

Comment: @RonJohn -- but there's rapid depreciation under [Section 179](https://www.irs.gov/newsroom/irs-issues-guidance-on-section-179-expenses-and-section-168g-depreciation-under-tax-cuts-and-jobs-act). I'm shocked to see that the limit is now $1,000,000; it was $50,000 when I learned the basics of US income taxes back in the 70s.